# In NXT, what is the difference from Account ID and Account Numeric ID?

Tags: wallet, nxt

For NXT, why are there 2 different ways of identifying your NXT account? There is a Account ID and Account Numeric ID.

What was the differences and why was it done like this?

What are advantages/disadvantages from using one or the other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> They represent both the same "information". The NXT-... is the same as
>   the ID but expressed in Reed Solomon format which among other things
>   has these benefits:
>
> 1. It can handle up to 2 typos, not that you should purposefully type it wrong, but if you write one or two wrong digits, your funds will
>      still go to the designated account. It is not infallible but it gives
>      an additional layer of "confidence".
> 2. It is easier to read. A long string of numbers is not the easiest thing to read/digit, you leave a digit behind or type one wrong and
>      your transaction goes to somebody else.
>
> more info:  http://wiki.nxtcrypto.org/wiki/RS_Address_Format

credit: https://nxtforum.org/nxt-helpdesk/why-two-different-account-numbers/

Answer (score 2):

Starting in software version 1.1.3, the numeric account format has been changed to [Reed-Solomon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reed%E2%80%93Solomon_error_correction) format by default (the account address starting with NXT- ) which provides higher security against typing mistakes. You still can use both address formats, but the new format is recommended.

Answer (score 1):

The new Reed-Solomon account number for Nxt Cryptocurrency will always start with NXT and is much easier to say. I imagine them on a piece of plastic like a credit card...

Accounts can also be represented by an alias which can be used to receive transactions.